# A new HttpSession for each request?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, httpsession

I've always taken for granted the `JSESSIONID` cookie created for every fresh request for a given client when developing applications using the servlet specification. But after giving it a bit of thought, isn't is more logical for the servlet container to create a cookie header only *after* the session has been requested and created in code? For clients who have their cookies disabled, won't it end up creating a new `HttpSession` for each request made?

Please let me know if the question is still unclear so I can edit it. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new Session will not be created by the Servlet container by default unless the Servlet actually creates it explicitly. Just because in the Header a JSEESIONID is being populated does not mean that there has to be a seesion on the server. An exception to this is in JSPs that by default create a Session if one is not there unless <%@ page session="false" %>

As far as not having cookies turned on:

> A web container can use several
>   methods to associate a session with a
>   user, all of which involve passing an
>   identifier between the client and the
>   server. The identifier can be
>   maintained on the client as a cookie,
>   or the web component can include the
>   identifier in every URL that is
>   returned to the client.
>
> If your application uses session
>   objects, you must ensure that session
>   tracking is enabled by having the
>   application rewrite URLs whenever the
>   client turns off cookies. You do this
>   by calling the response's
>   encodeURL(URL) method on all URLs
>   returned by a servlet. This method
>   includes the session ID in the URL
>   only if cookies are disabled;
>   otherwise, it returns the URL
>   unchanged.

Comment: That begs the question, what exactly is the purpose of generating the JSESSIONID in advance if the container is anyways not going to create a new session?

Comment: Oh well, I guess I'll just ask a new question for this query of mine. Thanks for the help.